# Не тот(,) что прежде - нужна ли запятая

Tags: запятая

Вроде бы устоявшееся выражение, но в большинстве текстов запятая все-таки ставится. Нужна или нет она здесь?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Запятая нужна: "Он не тот, что прежде".

Для сравнения:Здесь всё не так, как раньше.И разве так, как теперь, жил Париж!  Это устойчивые варианты сравнительных оборотов. Также: Он не тот, каким был прежде - в форме СПП с придаточным сравнительным.

Все эти обороты обособляются по формальному признаку, связанным с повтором местоимений вида ТАК…КАК, ТАКОЙ…КАК, ТОТ...ЧТО.